# Android delivered Message wrong number was work

Tags: android, sms, messaging

When I send a message with the wrong phone number (eg => 093485), the message was delivered.In fact, the message not be delivered

Why am I receiving `ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED` even when I send SMS to a invalid number m?

> My send Message Method:

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Helper.KEY_SIM_DELIVER, id);
        Intent deliverIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED);
        deliverIntent.putExtra(Helper.KEY_SIM_DELIVER, id);

        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(S.context, 0, sendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(S.context, 0, deliverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        int smsSize = 0;
        int length = message.length();

        if (length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {

            ArrayList<String> messagelist = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

            for (int i = 0; i < smsSize; i++) {

                sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(S.context, 0, sendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
                deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(S.context, 0, deliverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            }
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messagelist, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

        } else {
            minesCredit(isPesians, phoneNumber);
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
        }
```

> DeliveryBroadcastReceiver

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED)) {

            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK: {

                    String id = extras.getString(Helper.KEY_SIM_DELIVER);
                    Log.d(TAG, "SMS Delivered from =>" + id);

                    break;
                }
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "SMS not Delivered  =>");

                    break;
            }
        }
```

.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a Network issue.

To test, you can try to enable delivery report in another SMS App and check if you receive delivery notification after sending the SMS to same number.

**Backgroud**

Delivery report is just a SMS sent back from network to you saying that SMS was delivered... Then, Android notify all apps `ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED` intent.
If network send an SMS saying that SMS was delivered (even for a invalid number), there's nothing you can do...

Comment: When using the default SMS messages app to send a message to invalid numbers, their work and the message is not delivered